# Deep Linking - Redirect from facebook to ios app not working

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking, applinks

I am not able to redirect to my iOS app from facebook post. When I click on that post its gets open as webpage (somehow dosent identify tags for iOS & dosen't redirect to app). Not sure whether its a ios app OR html content or some other issue.

I have integrated Facebook APP Link meta tags in my HTML page like below.

in my case URLScheme name is  "fbXXXXXXX"

```
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content=<fb_APP_ID> />
 <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content=<appstoreid> />
 <meta property="al:ios:url" content="fbXXXXXXX://eventid/12345" />
 <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content=<App name> />
```

LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
```

[image]

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation
                ];

BFURL *parsedUrl = [BFURL URLWithInboundURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
if ([parsedUrl appLinkData]) {
    [self handleDeeplinkURL:url];

}

return YES;

}
```

Because sharing the URL directly works, I'm fairly confident I've set up deep linking correctly, so I think it must be something with open graph.

Comment: You want to open your when user click on some deep link within Facebook, like `my_app://showdashboard` , am I correct?

Comment: Are you set `URLSchemes`?

Comment: yes like that only

Comment: i already set URLScemes also it works proper for all scenario  like notepad to app ,email to app, etc etc  except facebook

Answer (score 0):

With link sharing you mean you are able to run your app with this link **myapp://eventid/12345** ?

If not you should check your Info.plist if you have registered URL Scheme for your application. The name for the scheme should be the same you've defined in facebook app settings, in your case it is "myapp"

[image: Info.plist screenshot]

Comment: I already set URL Scheme fbXXXXXXX . it works proper for all scenario like notepad to app ,email to app, etc etc but  except facebook

Comment: And do you have added your Bundle Id in the app settings on Facebook? Also you might have to add URL Identifier (your apps bundle id) to your URL Types

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an applinks issue, not an iOS uri scheme configuration issue.

It could be the case that Facebook has not yet scraped your webpage for those app links. You should put the link to your HTML page in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to test that your applinks metatags are working.